# Why does gravity make everything round?

Tags: gravity

I am studying ways to make an anti-gravity machine (!!). I believe it can be done, or theoretically be done using gravity itself as a "force" that pushes outwards instead of inwards.
A similar question was asked [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14280/why-are-planets-round), which speaks about why objects in the universe are round, which as stated, is due to Gravity.
I understand Gravity is the strongest, most consistent "force" in the universe and to traverse it we have to push against it - jets, propulsion, etc.
Never the less, I am perplexed why gravity's forces make objects round - eventually or over time. Why can't it turn a planet into a cube for example? Why can't Gravity make objects flat, and perhaps round at the perimeter?
If I can answer this question, I am sure I can find a way to "bend" Gravity for my invention.

Comment: Maybe you should start with Newtonian gravity... then invest a few years to a B.Sc. in physics, until you can discuss the foundations of general relativity. Could give your invention a bit more underpinning...

Comment: The 'why round' question is indeed answered in the other question you mention. For the rest there is nothing answerable in your question - voting to close as duplicate. It seems like you want proof that gravity does not necessarily make objects round - to support your own theory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are planets round?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/14280/why-are-planets-round)

Comment: google "why are planets round" (no quotes) and "potato radius" (in quotes) for starters. While anti-gravity might be possible, we've seen no evidence of it so far. Using gravity to cause repulsion might be possible, but you'd be relying on other forces for the actual repulsion itself. Example: the Sun's gravity will cause it to go nova, exploding outwards, at some point, but that's ultimately a nuclear reaction, not a gravitational one.

Comment: why are soap bubbles round, its the least surface area for a given volume, lowest energy state.  It also distributes the gravity equally, if the earth ( will call it squerth, square earth ) was square gravity would be strongest across the corners ( diagonal through the center of squerth), the matter that makes up squerth is generally not strong enough to resist this ( think of it like sand ).  So naturally everything falls to the lowest energy state.  What is that entropy or something?

Comment: 1/r^2 is symmetric about a point.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix - Yes, it's entropy (or something). An oblate spheroid whose surface has a uniform gravitational + centrifugal potential energy is the most favored state from the point of view of entropy. Whether an object can get to (or get close to) that entropically-favored state depends very much on size. Small objects can't get there. Large objects can get very close.

Comment: Since our current knowledge of physics renders an "anti-gravity machine" impossible, just make it up *without* giving a detailed scientific explanation, same as they do for human teleportation, photon torpedos, traction beams, light sabres, "jumping to light speed", fighter spaceships that make noises like aeroplanes as they bank at impossible angles, etc.

Comment: van de walls force also makes water round in space. same with soap bubbles, good illustration by artistic pheonix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason gravity creates round objects is because the equation describing the force of gravity is the following.

$$F_G = -\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$$

where $G$ is the gravitational constant, $m_1$ and $m_2$ are two point masses which are gravitationally attracting one another, and $r$ is the distance between (the center of mass of) the two masses.

If you think about if for a minute, it should be abundantly clear that gravity causes objects to be round because **gravity is only dependent on distance and not on any angle or orientation.**

That means if I take a planet and throw additional mass onto it, gravity will cause that mass to be attracted to the center of mass of that planet. There's no other way in which gravity can act upon it. If everything is equally pulled towards the center, the only possible object you can form is a sphere.

Of course there are objects like asteroids which aren't round, but that's because the structural integrity of the rocks is actually stronger than gravity and gravity, while still trying to make the asteroid round, just can't overcome the strength in the rocks.

Comment: $F=-Gm_1m_2/r^2$ is valid only for objects with a spherical mass distribution.

Comment: @DavidHammen That is true, I've amended to say I'm referring to point masses. I referenced the equation to imply that is the source of calculating gravitational forces. Sure, you can create some non-spherically symmetric gravitational force via a non-spherical mass distribution, but ultimately, I believe I my point still remains that at its core, gravity forms spherical objects because the attraction between any two (point) masses is not dependent on angle.

Comment: @DavidHammen There might be a few steps of logic between the base equation of gravity and how a large, square planet (for example) would ultimately become spherical, but I don't believe my statement is wrong.

Comment: A central force does not prohibit non-spherical objects. The discussion should be based on minimising the total energy and indeed, rotating stars and planets are not spherical despite obeying the same gravitational laws.

Comment: @RobJeffries I never said you couldn't get non-spherical objects and in fact I touched upon an example of why you may still get non-spherical objects despite my explanation. And if you're going to describe your answer in terms of minimizing total energy, my response would be, what determines the minimum energy? The answer to that, fundamentally is that the force (and likewise the potential energy) only depends on distance and not orientation. If that wasn't true, gravity wouldn't make things spherical. There's a lot of concepts on top of that, but I believe my answer gets to the core.

Comment: Your answer provides an obvious explanation for why the OP's "anti-gravity machine" is impossible (at least at the macro scale): for F to be positive i.e. repulsive, one of the masses would have to be negative.

Comment: @Chappo See this [related question/answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/21849/why-is-gravity-only-an-attractive-force/21852#21852) on that point.

Comment: This made perfect sense to me. I am into maths anyway :) Thank you.

Comment: This  is not the correct answer, very much so.

Comment: @DavidHammen We can agree to disagree. The question was specifically why does **gravity** make things round, not why are objects under the influence of gravity and other forces not round? I answer the question as asked.

Answer (score 11):

> I am studying ways to make an anti-gravity machine (!!).  I believe it can be done, or theoretically be done using gravity itself as a "force" that pushes outwards instead of inwards.

It doesn't work that way.  No one has found a repulsive version of gravity and there is no evidence this is even possible.

And in science, we go by the evidence.

> A similar question was asked here, which speaks about why objects in the universe are round, which as stated, is due to Gravity.

Which the question's answer explains by the *attractive* nature of gravity.  No evidence (that word again) of repulsion.

> I understand Gravity is the strongest, most consistent "force" in the universe

You understand wrong.

It is considered the *weakest* of the fundamental forces.  This [Physics SE answer explains why](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4243/what-does-it-mean-to-say-gravity-is-the-weakest-of-the-forces#4255).

It appears to be strong only because on average, over a large scale, matter is generally neutrally charged, whereas mass (and energy) just gets bigger the more space you have (a little simplistic, but that's the general idea).

As for "consistent", well all the forces behave consistently or we would not be able to model them with mathematics.

> and to traverse it we have to push against it - jets, propulsion, etc.

More *evidence* for no repulsion !

> Never the less, I am perplexed why gravity's forces make objects round - eventually or over time. Why can't it turn a planet into a cube for example? Why can't Gravity make objects flat, and perhaps round at the perimeter ?

Because these are unstable configurations.  Even if they could form from natural processes (which is unlikely as I'll explain) the resulting forces and stresses (for large objects) would be too great to prevent collapse into a more stable shape.

Now smaller objects can form less rounded shapes - small asteroids can be all sorts of shapes.  Only their relatively small mass (and hence small gravity) allows them to resist compression into "nicer" round shapes.

But larger objects have lots of gravity simply because the have lots of mass.  The materials they are made of will not withstand compressive forces on them and they will form roughly round shapes, because that's the most resistive configuration.

So why more-or-less spherical ?

Because these larger objects tend to form in a way that builds up material equally all over the surface, so there is some tendency to be spherically symmetrical just from the way material accretes as it grows.

However once they get really big (planets, larger moons and so on) the forces on the materials will be so great that they will as a general rule, behave a little like fluids.  And fluids will end up in that nice spherical shape as they lack the rigidity to resist compression.  Again a little simplistic, but this gets really complicated quite quickly.  They key here is to stop thinking of e.g. rocky planets as rigid objects.  Maybe on a timescale of seconds they are, but on astronomical timescales they're not so rigid.

So for larger objects, more-or-less spherical is inevitable simply because they're large.

> If I can answer this question, I am sure I can find a way to "bend" Gravity for my invention.

No anti-gravity to be seen here.

Really, learn the basics of physics if your interested and hopefully you'll find that not only is it interesting, but it can explain things without the need to invent other explanations.  Usually. :-)

Answer (score 7):

> I understand Gravity is the strongest, most consistent "force" in the universe.

As noted in other answers, you understand incorrectly. Gravitation is the weakest of the four fundamental forces. Gravitation is such a minuscule force at the atomic level that it is hard to distinguish whether gravitation acts as predicted on antimatter (theoretically the same as how gravitation acts on matter).

Gravitation emerges as a powerful force at the level of stars and planets because the two strongest fundamental forces, the strong and weak interactions, are extremely short range, and because the electromagnetic force is limited by the fact that macro scale objects tend to be electrically neutral. Gravitation remains in play because it has infinite extent and because mass, at least theoretically, is never negative.

This, by the way, argues against your premise of creating antigravity. As far as we known, all objects (including antimatter) have a positive mass, and hence there is no such thing as antigravity.

> Why does gravity make everything round?

Gravity does not make everything round. Small objects tend to have a fractal shape. Somewhat larger objects, where gravitation plays some role, tend to look like misshapen potatoes. It's only with sufficiently large objects, where gravitation plays a dominant role, that things begin to appear round.

An object needs to be a few hundred kilometers in diameter before self-gravitation can overcome the electromagnetic ability of smaller clumps of matter to maintain whatever non-spherical shape they happen to have. The size at which gravitation begins to make things "roundish" is called the potato radius.

The potato radius depends on an object's composition. Rock has a much higher yield strength than does ice. Icy objects that formed in the outer solar system tend to be "roundish" when their diameter exceed 400 kilometers, but potato shaped when they are less than this size. For stony objects, the relevant size between lumpy potato and more or less roundishness is about twice that of an icy object.

> Why can't it turn a planet into a cube for example?

Because the potential energy due to self gravitation (and due to rotation in the case of a rotating object) at the surface of a cube is not uniform. This non-uniform energy distribution means the object has excess energy. This excess energy is minuscule for a cube the size of a die but is huge for a cube the size of a planet.

The mantles of terrestrial planets are solid, more or less. (It is highly erroneous to think of the Earth's mantle as molten. It isn't.) That "more or less" is important. A better description is that the mantles of the terrestrial planets are elastoplastic, or perhaps even viscoelastoplastic. They deform elastically in response to short-term stresses and strains, plastically in response to longer term stresses and strains, and can even flow over even longer periods of time. This means that a cube the size of a planet will eventually deform into something close to the entropically-favored spherical or oblate spheroid shape.

Gravitation and non-conservative interactions can shape very large and very diffuse objects into a shape that is markedly non-spherical. An interstellar gas cloud, for example, eventually collapses into a disk shaped object with a massive protostar in the center. Given the right conditions, an interstellar gas cloud initially collapses toward a spherical shape, but pancakes once enough material concentrates at the center of the cloud. Here volume is not anything close to a conserved quantity. Angular momentum is however close to a conserved quantity. This, coupled with collisions and gravitation, is what make such gas clouds collapse into circumstellar disks.

Comment: In the minutes after `21:40` in https://www.ted.com/talks/richard_feynman Feynman points out what you mention, that at larger scales, we don't notice the electric force because of charge cancellation (until one tries to push one's had through the chair). Of course it is the electromagnetic force on the atomic scale that keeps gravity from causing planet self-implosion in the first place!

Answer (score 3):

> Never the less, I am perplexed why gravity's forces make objects round
>   - eventually or over time. Why can't it turn a planet into a cube for example?

Think of an Earth-size cube as a planet with 8 HUGE mountains on it.  In fact, these mountains would be so huge that the bottom of the mountains couldn't support the top of the mountains.  As they collapse, the mountains would flow toward the centers of the cube faces.  The end result would be almost a sphere.

It might make it easier to visualize if you consider a cubical planet made entirely of water.  Clearly the tops of the "water mountains" would flow down into the "valleys".

Comment: +1 The "water mountain" analogy makes this really easy to understand for a layperson :-)